# How to handle external database updates in react-native/redux?

Tags: react-native, redux

I am creating a react-native mobile app for a service that has to interact with the service's API to get and update data.

This service also has a web interface through which users can sign in and use the service (aka getting and updating data.

Since I am only developing the mobile applications, I have no access to the code on the web side of things and my only way to make changes to that code is to go through someone else.

From the resources available online, I feel like I should be able to make a mobile app that interacts with and updates data through the API, however my thought process for how I am going to handle a user updating data through the web interface and reflecting that in the app has hit a standstill.

Does anyone know of a term that I can use to describe this in such a way that I will likely find more results online (or even better, a react-native npm package that achieves this functionality)?

So far I have tried searching the following, but have found few results:

- redux caching
- handling data updated on the server redux
- redux how to handle data changing on the server
- how to handle database updates redux

Comment: Do you want *live* updates? Usually (at least in my experience), a refresh mechanism involving a requery is enough UX-wise.

Comment: live updates would be ideal, although I might be able to settle for some kind of delayed update every X period of time. My main concerns are having the apps redux store and the database behind the API becoming out of sync and having conflicting information.

Comment: although the thought just occurred to me that if the server/API backend stores the time things were last updated then i could compare that to a last updated time generated by the app and see which change is most recent

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Sockets.io](https://socket.io/) seems like it would work for realtime updates.

Essentially, it works by shifting the connection from a request-based HTTP deal (where the client asks the server for stuff) to a websocket in which the client and server can send each other things (like database changes :D) over a constantly open stream, even if after a delay.

Comment: Not sure how this would integrate with the PHP in the API backend but